# API route not working in a NextJS app (Firebase)

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, routes, next.js, next.js13

I am working on a NextJS app (on Firebase), and I want to create an API route to perform some specific task on the realtime database.

For some reason what I tried did not work. I hope some expert eyes can bring me useful help.

I started from what I know is already working in the app and what I know about API routes.

To start with here is some working code I have written for this app:

```
    'use client';

    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import firebase from "../../firebase/initFirebase";
    import "./shopList.css";
    .....


    export default function THE_RecordList({}: {}) {
        const [dataRcdArray, setDataRcdArray] = useState<never[]>([]);
        .....
    
      useEffect(() => {
            firebase.database().ref('TheDataCollection')
            .on("value", snapshot => {
                // The next line avoids displaying multiple times the list, when reloading the page.
                setDataRcdArray([])
                snapshot.forEach((item:firebase.database.DataSnapshot) => {
            const rcdSnpSht = item as firebase.database.DataSnapshot
                
            if (rcdSnpSht.child('status').val() == 'D') return
                
            setDataRcdArray(arr => [...arr, item] as never[])
                })
            });
        }, [])
    }
```

Then following is what is not working and I would like to work.
Inside the *app* directory I have created a subdirectory called *api* and inside it *sroute* (special route).
And this is the contents of the file *app/api/sroute/routes.ts* :

```
import {NextResponse} from 'next/server';
import firebase from "../../../firebase/initFirebase";


export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const paramName = 'number'
  const nbrPos = request.url.search(paramName) + paramName.length + 1
  const nbrStr = request.url.substring(nbrPos)
  const nbrVal = parseInt(nbrStr)

  if (isNaN(nbrVal)) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: 'A number must be provided, in the "'+paramName+'" parameter, for this API to work.'
    }, {status: 200});
  }

  if (nbrVal<=0) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: 'A strictly positive number must be provided, for this API to work.'
    }, {status: 200});
  }

    let nbrFound = -1

    firebase.database().ref('TheDataCollection')
  .on("value", snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((item:firebase.database.DataSnapshot) => {
      const rcdSnpSht = item as firebase.database.DataSnapshot

      if (rcdSnpSht.child('historicalOrder').val() != nbrVal) return

      nbrFound = rcdSnpSht.child('historicalOrder').val()
    })
  });

  if (nbrFound == nbrVal)
    return NextResponse.json({
      order: nbrVal,
      status: 'FOUND !!'
    }, {status: 200});
  else
    return NextResponse.json({
      order: nbrVal,
      status: 'NOTHING FOUND !!'
    }, {status: 200});
} /* End of GET */
```

This last chunk of code is not working. And below is what I get as error message in the terminal where I ran the command:

```
    % npm run dev

    - error StaticGenBailoutError: Page with `dynamic = "error"` couldn't be rendered statically because it used `request.url`.
at Object.staticGenerationBailout (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/static-generation-bailout.js:27:15)
at handleReqBailout (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/helpers/proxy-request.js:93:23)
at Object.get (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/helpers/proxy-request.js:101:13)
at GET (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/close/route.ts:15:28)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:242:43)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:111:36)
at NoopContextManager.with (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:360:30)
at ContextAPI.with (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:30:58)
at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:953:34)
at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:993:36)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:100:107)
at NoopContextManager.with (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:360:30)
at ContextAPI.with (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:30:58)
at NextTracerImpl.trace (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:100:32)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:230:53)
at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:330:14)
at Object.wrap (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/async-storage/static-generation-async-storage-wrapper.js:39:24)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:184:97)
at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:330:14)
at Object.wrap (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/async-storage/request-async-storage-wrapper.js:77:24)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:183:75)
at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:330:14)
at AppRouteRouteModule.execute (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:180:56)
at AppRouteRouteModule.handle (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:303:41)
at RouteHandlerManager.handle (/Users/me/Documents/FireBase/njsapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-handler-managers/route-handler-manager.js:28:29)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async doRender (/Users/me/Documents/FireBase/njsapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:936:38)
at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (/Users/me/Documents/FireBase/njsapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1162:28)
at async /Users/me/Documents/FireBase/njsapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:99:36 {
      code: 'NEXT_STATIC_GEN_BAILOUT'
    }
```

And finally in case this may be useful, this is part of what I have inside *package.json*:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.2.6",
    "@types/react": "18.2.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
    "firebase": "^9.22.2",
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.1.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a bug on newer versions of NextJS related to fetching from dynamic routes.

Try adding this line at the end of your routes.ts file:

```
export const dynamic = "force-static";
```

More info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config)

Comment: I just tried your suggestion; unfortunately it does not change much, it is still not working. I get this message in the browser web developer tools console: "GET
http://localhost:3000/sroute   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 28ms]" repeatedly. Beside you mention "dynamic routes", but I don't think what I am doing here is dynamic routing (tell me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 2):

This is happen because of next js static export.in my case i use app router.
one way to fix this
open next.config.js
and remove this
**output: 'export',**

restart server and then try again.

Comment: This work, also when I build a production bundle working without removing the `output: 'export'`